# Django Prefetch related query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am having two models Customer and Contact where I want to add fields from Contact model to Customer model and access the values of it.How to solve it?
Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
     code = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=30)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Contact(models.Model):
     partner_name =models.ForeignKey(Customer,blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     contact_number=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
     email=models.EmailField(max_length=50,blank=True)
```

I tried this query

```
q=Customer.objects.filter(name='xxx').prefetch_related('contact_set')

for i in q:
 print(i.contact_set)
```

It returns

```
partner.Contact.None
partner.Contact.None
partner.Contact.None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fetch the data before printing it using `QuerySet.all()`:

```
q = Customer.objects.filter(name='xxx').prefetch_related('contact_set')

for i in q:
    print(i.contact_set.all())
```

Comment: but i want to add field from contact model to customer model.How to do that?

Comment: You can not, because there can be several or zero contacts for 1 customer. If you are sure there is only one - use OneToOne instead of ForeignKey. With current model you can use `i.contact_set.first().contact_number` But it will fail if there are no Contact objects at all. And it looks wrong because you may miss other contacts.